# Positive definiteness of MM'

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $M$ is a $k\times l$ matrix of rank $l$. Can we say $MM'$ is positive definite, as $x'MM'x = (M'x)' (I) (M'x)$ and $I$ is positive definite?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it is positive semi-definite. It could happen that is it not positive definite. In particular, if $k>l$, $MM'$ is a $k\times k$ matrix but has only rank $l$ according to your assumption, so it cant be positive definite.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it is not positive definite. But couldn't find its logic. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

$x'MM'x=(M'x)'I(M'x)=0$ implies that $M'x=0$. Now use the rank to solve the problem.

Comment: How do you equate $(M'x)'I(M'x) = 0$? It is $\geq 0$?

Comment: $(M'x)'I(M'x)$ is the inner product of the vector $M'x$ by itself and it is $\geq 0$. (In fact you can omit $I$.)

Answer (score 0):

$(M'x)'(M'x)$ is the norm of the vector $M'x$, so it is surely positive, as long as $x$ doesn't belong to the kernel of $M'$.